# Test if a string has been encrypted using mcrypt_encode in php?

Tags: php, mcrypt

Is there a way in PHP to test if a string has been encrypted using [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/mcrypt_encrypt)?

Comment: Do you want to test if it s a valid encrypted string (even if it may not be encrypted) or if it was actually encrypted? If the 2nd one, I tink you could give up, you won't know if that is an actual string (perhaps waiting for encryption) or something encrypted.

Comment: as opposed to encrypted with some other function?

Comment: there is no way for php to know if a string has been encrypted or not.
as @Mark B. already mentioned it the only way is to try decrypt it(but if you can see the data you will know or at least you are capable of making a guess is it encrypted or not) and that makes it useless to check. You should know, if data is supposed to be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not written what you're actually concerned about specifically, but:

Whether or not some data has been encrypted is not dependent on which encryption function has been used but which encryption algorithm. Say, if somebody has encrypted something in PERL or in PHP - you can't tell by having the encrypted string.

So as this applies, you can't tell for `mcrypt_encrypt`. That function does not leave any sign inside the encrypted data.

However, if you have the key and the original text (plain) as well as the algorithm, you can reverse what `mcrypt_encrypt` does with [`mcrypt_decrypt`](http://php.net/mcrypt_decrypt). You can then compare the plains and if they match you can say that the plain was encrypted with the specific key and algorithm.

As we're talking about encryption, this is normally not the case, you don't have the plain.

However, you can create a checksum of the plain and encrypt it as well. Then you can decrypt it later on and compare it with a checksum of the plain you encrypted as well to tell if the data was successfully decrypted. But as this shows, this is actually additional information next to the encrypted data.

If you add more information what you're looking for, it might be possible to give more helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

when encrypting add some static text to your string ; when cheking use mcrypt_encode again with static text this time without original string see if encrypted static text exist in encrypted string . it should work

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean `mcrypt_encrypt()`? There is no mcrypt_encode() function.

No. A properly encrypted string should be indistinguishable from random garbage. The only way to test a crypted string to see if it's crypted is to decrypt it.